# Are Intel i7 core mobile processors decent enough for software development?

Tags: java, eclipse, database, ide, microsoft-surface-pro

I'm reaching out because I'm in the market for a new laptop, and I would like something light that I can take with me for a job interview or meet clients,  so I can demonstrate my source code and execute my applications.   Since some of the 2 in 1's in the market have the Intel i7 core mobile processor,  I want to know if a surface 3 pro or a Lenovo yoga pro 2 in 1 are decent enough to run ide's (visual studio and eclipse), database management systems, and execute programs.   All my programs are small, I just want the option to be mobile and productive.  I know that we can install desktop applications on a surface 3 pro,  but I would like to know if they would be efficient.

Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't they be?

Comment: They *can* run them.  *Efficiency* is opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Core i7 processor is the top-of-the line processor in Intel's processor lineup.  The "mobile" variant is a low-power version, but that does not mean it's slower.  It will still be faster than an i5.

So to answer your question, yes, an i7 mobile is perfectly adequate for what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much.   I was concerned about performance because even the i7 Mobile processor is only dual-core.   I'm not looking to replace my powerhouse.   I just want something very light with a decent performance.

Comment: My laptop has a 3rd-generation mobile i7 processor in it. It's still faster than my 4th-gen i5 desktop CPU at work.